# Extending builtin classes in python

Tags: python, string, monkeypatching

How can I extend a builtin class in python?
I would like to add a method to the str class.
I've done some searching but all I'm finding is older posts, I'm hoping someone knows of something newer.

Comment: See also <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192649/can-you-monkey-patch-methods-on-core-types-in-python>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you monkey patch methods on core types in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192649/can-you-monkey-patch-methods-on-core-types-in-python)

Comment: Why would this be preferred over a function that takes a string?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just subclass the type

```
>>> class X(str):
...     def my_method(self):
...         return int(self)
...
>>> s = X("Hi Mom")
>>> s.lower()
'hi mom'
>>> s.my_method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in my_method
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Hi Mom'

>>> z = X("271828")
>>> z.lower()
'271828'
>>> z.my_method()
271828
```

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't have to subclass but after some more research I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible any other way, so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Unkwntech: Can't imagine a better way than subclassing.  Seriously.  Whatever you had in mind (monkeypatching?) never seems to work out as well as a clear, precise, obvious subclass.

Comment: @S.Lott - Ruby's open classes and C#'s extension methods come to mind.

Comment: @orip: Aware of these.  Find monkeypatching in all forms to be a management nightmare -- they effectively prevent reuse by injecting features in obscure ways.

Comment: In this sample type(z.lower()) is str an not X. How to keep it an X ?

Comment: @dagfr by overriding the .lower() method in the X class and returning a new X object

Answer (score 18):

One way could be to use the "class reopening" concept (natively existing in Ruby) that can be implemented in Python using a class decorator.
An exemple is given in this page:
http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2007/08/opening-python-classes.html

I quote:

I think with class decorators you could do this:

```
@extend(SomeClassThatAlreadyExists)
class SomeClassThatAlreadyExists:
    def some_method(self, blahblahblah):
        stuff
```

Implemented like this:

```
def extend(class_to_extend):
    def decorator(extending_class):
        class_to_extend.__dict__.update(extending_class.__dict__)
        return class_to_extend
    return decorator
```

Comment: Python 3.9, `__dict__` is no longer a `dict` but a `mappingproxy`, you have to use @MVP's solution instead.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you can not change builtin classes.
To simulate a "class reopening" like Ruby in Python3 where `__dict__` is an mappingproxy object and not dict object :

```
def open(cls):
  def update(extension):
    for k,v in extension.__dict__.items():
      if k != '__dict__':
        setattr(cls,k,v)
    return cls
  return update


class A(object):
  def hello(self):
    print('Hello!')

A().hello()   #=> Hello!

#reopen class A
@open(A)
class A(object):
  def hello(self):
    print('New hello!')
  def bye(self):
    print('Bye bye')


A().hello()   #=> New hello!
A().bye()     #=> Bye bye
```

In Python2 I could also write a decorator function 'open' as well:

```
def open(cls):
  def update(extension):
    namespace = dict(cls.__dict__)
    namespace.update(dict(extension.__dict__))
    return type(cls.__name__,cls.__bases__,namespace)
  return update
```

Comment: At last I can do this like in Ruby. Works like a charm. I prefer the second definition.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is quite old now, but just in case someone comes here later, there's a library that allows actually extending built-ins types.

Available for Python 3.7 - 3.11.

[ExType](https://pypi.org/project/extype/#built-in-extensions)

**Disclaimer:** I'm one of the authors

Comment: Excellent project, going into my bookmarks as I see myself using it in the future