# python adding new methods to built-in types

Tags: python, function, chaining

How would I go about writing python functions that can be append to strings (or other object)?

for example:

```
"FOO".lower()
```

How do they receive input?
Are they generators?

I will happily read up on it, but I don't really know what I am looking for.

Comment: It is a [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings are objects and thus have methods. `lower()` is one of them.

You cannot add a custom method to `str`, `unicode` or any other builtin (written in C) classes - see [Implementing a custom string method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519702/implementing-a-custom-string-method) and [Extending builtin classes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352537/extending-builtin-classes-in-python)

Comment: thanks... I feel really stupid now, completely forgot that str was it's own class! make's far more sense!

Answer (score 2):

They are not generators.  They are simply [methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29) defined on the `string` class.

You could create your own like this:

```
>>> class MyString(str):
...   def reversed(self):
...     return self[::-1]
... 
>>> x = MyString('spam and eggs')
>>> x.reversed()
'sgge dna maps'
```