# How to create an extension method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to create an extension method in Python for `datetime` objects? I.e. I would like to create a date `date = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 2)` and use my extension method which will do sth with that date by simply typing `date.my_extension(args)`. Is it possible and if not, what is the best alternative for that?

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352537/extending-builtin-classes-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192649/can-you-monkey-patch-methods-on-core-types-in-python already?

Comment: Why not just write a function and use it like `my_extension(date, args)`? What exactly are you trying to achieve? I sense an XY problem.

Comment: you make a subclass of it and add whatever you want to it