# I can’t make a function where the input goes behind the function name

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

So I want to make a function like `.isalpha()` or `.isnumerc()`. Basically, a function where the input is before the command name.
Here’s an example:

```py
def string.text():
  print(string)
```

But that doesn’t work. It just says “Invalid Syntax”

I was expecting it to work like `.lower()` or `.isnumeric()` or `.isalpha()` or all those functions that have the input behind the function name.

Comment: take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352537/extending-builtin-classes-in-python  you need to create a subclass of string and add there your own methods.

Comment: These are called "class/instance methods`. You create a class (possibly subclassing some other class) and then implement a method for this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [sub classes](https://www.codesdope.com/course/python-subclass-of-a-class/) in python

You have a base class such as `str` and a class that inherits from it eg: `CustomStr`

```py
class CustomStr(str):
    def text(self):
       return "text"
```

Now simply create an instance of this class and you invoke your custom function on it

```py
s = CustomStr("Hello world")
s.text()
>>text
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is creating a method in an Object Oriented Programming language (which python can be)

here is a good explanation: https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/method#:~:text=In%20object%2Doriented%20programming%20(OOP,the%20object%20that%20calls%20it.

but the gist is that you can create methods (just like functions but specific to a particular class) and then the way to call those methods is exactly how you described:

```
class.method()
```

Don't forget to put self as the first argument for the method.

I hope this helps