# Python: How to mock date in source file from test file?

Tags: python, mocking

consider this method in `manager.py`

```
def get_start_end_time_for(user, year, month):
    today = datetime.today()
    if today.day  < user.financial_day_of_month:
        if month == 1:
            month = 12
            year -= 1
        else:
            month -= 1

    time_from = date(day=user.financial_day_of_month,
                     month=month, year=year)
    time_to = time_from + relativedelta(months=+1)

    return time_from, time_to
```

consider the following in `test.py`

```
def test_get_start_end_time_for(user, year, month):
    # mock datetime.datetime.today in manager.py
    # do further steps
```

I looked at [Python: Trying to mock datetime.date.today() but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/python-trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working) but it seems you can only mock something with in the test method

How can I mock `datetime.datetime.today` in `manager.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest strategies is to wrap `datetime.today()` in a method. It could look something like this:

```
def get_start_end_time_for(user, year, month):
    today = get_today()
    ...

def get_today():
    return datetime.today()
```

Then in `test.py`, you would mock it by mocking the `getToday()` method as follows:

```
@patch('get_today')
def test_get_start_end_time_for(user, year, month, get_today_mock):
    get_today_mock.return_value = #whatever date you want to use for your test
```