# Set the date/time for a python script in linux

Tags: python, linux

I am unit testing a python script and want to simulate the running of the script on different days of the month.

Is there any way to set the date/time for when launching the script from the command line?

I do not have access to change the system date/time, and would prefer to not hack the script with the dates I want to test for.

Cheers,
Donal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found the solution, use a linux tool called faketime.

```
[10:45:03] $ faketime '2008-12-24 08:15:42' /bin/date
Wed Dec 24 08:15:42 GMT 2008
```

Comment: I tried when I wrote it, but it won't let me accept my own answer for another two days.

Answer (score 1):

You may probably achieve this by some LD_PRELOAD trick, but in my opinion much cleaner solution is to mock datetime.date class. For more details you may check answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/python-trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to directly set the date/time in a shell so that the system time is unaltered but different for a sub shell

However there are two solutions

1) for a limited set of different times you can use TZ, example

```
TZ="GMT+6" date
```

2) run the python programs in a VM like Virtualbox and *do* set the system time.  In the VM!