# How to mock/set system date in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

In some of my tests I am having a problem that they fail on Travis because of time and time zone problems, so I want to mock system time for my test. How can I do this?

Comment: What time function do you want to mock? If it's the Python datetime, it's a little tricky as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/python-trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working)

Comment: I want to do this for all modules. I think the freezegun example works in the link you gave. Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't mock builtin methods.

One approach I have often done is to change my code a bit to not use `datetime` directly to obtain the date, but a wrapper function somewhere:

```
# mymodule.py

def get_today():
   return datetime.date.today()
```

This makes it trivial to just `mock` it in your test:

```
def test_something():
    with mock.patch('mymodule.get_today', return_value=datetime.date(2014, 6, 2)):
        ...
```

You can also use the [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) module.

Comment: `setattr(datetime.datetime, 'today', get_today)` ?

Comment: As mentioned, this gives `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'datetime.datetime'` on Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Ah, yes. You have to replace the complete class `datetime`. You can inherit from datetime and override the methods you need. But `freezetime` works perfectly.

Comment: I think that the idea of a wrapper function is the best answer given across every thread I've found because it is agnostic to unit testing libraries so it will always work.

Answer (score 44):

@Brian-Kruger's answer is the best one. I've voted to undelete it. In the meantime...

Use [freezegun](https://pypi.org/project/freezegun) ([repo](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun)).

From the README:

```
from freezegun import freeze_time

@freeze_time("2012-01-14")
def test():
    assert datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 14)
```

Comment: This answer is a lot more suitable for SO than the deleted one, thanks for re-posting it

Answer (score 18):

There are two ways you can accomplish that:

1. Create function which you will call instead of `datetime.datetime.now()` as suggested by Bruno, but here is different implementation:

   ```
   import os
   import datetime

   def mytoday():
    if 'MYDATE' in os.environ:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(os.getenv('MYDATE'), '%m-%d-%Y').date()
    else:
        return datetime.date.today()
   ```

   Then, in your test, you just monkeypatch environment variable:

   ```
   import datetime

   def test_patched_date(monkeypatch):
       monkeytest.setenv('MYDATE', '05-31-2014')
       assert datetime.date.today() == datetime.date(2014, 5, 31)
   ```
2. Monkeypatch the `datetime` function:

   ```
   import datetime
   import pytest

   FAKE_TIME = datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 25, 17, 05, 55)

   @pytest.fixture
   def patch_datetime_now(monkeypatch):

       class mydatetime:
           @classmethod
           def now(cls):
               return FAKE_TIME

       monkeypatch.setattr(datetime, 'datetime', mydatetime)


   def test_patch_datetime(patch_datetime_now):
       assert datetime.datetime.now() == FAKE_TIME
   ```

Comment: is the indentation correct or something missing? after "def patch_datetime_now(monkeypatch): " there is no indented block. maybe at least add a comment in this code line, it confuses some people like me

Comment: For the second suggestion, if the module under test loads the datetime before patching (e.g. `from datetime import datetime`), it will hold an instance to the old datetime and not `mydatetime`.

Comment: I now realise I was referring to [this gotcha](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) of patching. So, if the module under test (mut.py) imports datetime before you get to patch `datetime.datetime`, patch `mut.datetime` instead.

Comment: Nice to get a Pytest `monkeypatch` solution instead of the repetitive `mock` solutions, but you may need to tweak the `now` method prototype especially if you are using timezone aware dates and `ruff`: `def now(cls, *args, **kwargs):  # noqa: ARG004`

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use this code.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


@pytest.fixture
def mocking_datetime_now(monkeypatch):
    datetime_mock = MagicMock(wrap=datetime.datetime)
    datetime_mock.now.return_value = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 0, 0, 0)

    monkeypatch.setattr(datetime, "datetime", datetime_mock)


@pytest.fixture
def setup_db(company, company_user, mocking_datetime_now):
    assert datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Trying to use this, but from `conftest.py`. Yeah, I add it to the test parameters `def test_foo(mocking_datetime_now)`, but then what?

Comment: For my situation, I'm realizing now for my situation, mocking the entire class is problematic since I need to use `strptime` elsewhere.