# Patterns for unit testing a Flask app that depends on timestamps?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have a Flask app that's part of a task scheduling system. The business logic in many of the routes relies on the current time.

```
@app.route("/do_stuff")
def do_stuff():
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  call_func(request.args.get("some_arg"), now)
```

I need to bring these functions under test. The tests will need to spoof timestamps, so that I can verify that the app responds properly depending on when various commands arrive.

Are there standard patterns for writing these kinds of tests in Flask? I can think of a bunch of clunky, non-DRY ways to do it. Wondering if there are any more elegant patterns/tools...?

Comment: You can use `pytest` and `pytest-flask` for general Flask testing. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988853/how-to-mock-set-system-date-in-pytest) for `datetime.datetime.now()` spoofing.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute `datetime.now()` with a mock implementation. For example in Python 3 there's the [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#partial-mocking) which implements this approach.

Comment: You can check out [Pytest](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html?highlight=mock)

Comment: You can install `mock` in python 2.7 through pypi.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I'd love to find something cleaner:

```
@app.route("/do_stuff")
def do_stuff():
  if app.debug and request.args.get("now"):
    now = request.args.get("now")
  else:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()      
  call_func(request.args.get("some_arg"), now)
```

With that logic around `now`, I can pass an optional `now` argument. If we're running in debug mode, then it can override the normal logic to fetch the current time.