Pytest mocking date from a function
So I have a function that creates a pandas dataframe with multiple columns of which one is a datetime column representing the entry_date of that particular instance. Now, I want to do a pytest testing of the function but the problem is that when constructing the pandas dataframe, there is a filter on the entry_date which takes only the entries of the past 2 weeks. I have constructed some mock files to test the functionality, but when calling the function because of the entry_date filter the dataframe remains empty if the 2 weeks exceed. I am trying to freeze_time for the testing, but it does not do the trick when calling the function and creating the dataframe.
Here is some code to get a view and maybe a better understanding of what I'm trying to do:
def create_dataframe(Inherit_from_parent):
   tb1 = get_table("People")
   tb2 = get_table("Record")
   query = sa.select(tb1.c.id, tb1.c.name, *tb1.c.entry_date,* ... 
          from .... where *t*b1.entry_date >= date_today() - text('interval "2 weeks"')**)


@pytest.fixture
def engine_factory(postgresql):
    def _get_engine(prefix):
        engine = get_database_engine(
            postgresql.info.dbname,
            username=postgresql.info.user,
            password=postgresql.info.password,
            host=postgresql.info.host,
            port=postgresql.info.port,
    )

    tables = {prefix + "_records": "record", prefix + "_people": "people"}

    for filename, tablename in tables.items():
        df = pd.read_parquet(f".{PATH}{filename}.parquet")
        df.to_sql(tablename, engine, index=False)

    return engine

return _get_engine

@freeze_time("2024-04-23")
def test_create_dataframe():
   people_ids = [1,2]

   df = create_dataframe(Parent_class_info(people_ids,*kwargs)
   df_expected = pd.read_parquet('{PATH}/df_expected.parquet')

   pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df, df_expected)

Now, the test works if I put the @freeze_time and the entry_date of the table  to current date but fails once the dates are too much in the past. On short, how can I mock a datetime column of a table which is created in a function, considering that the query to construct the dataframe has this filter on the datetime column?

Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988853/how-to-mock-set-system-date-in-pytest can help you.

Thanks for it but it doesn't seem to solve my problem :/
