# freeze_time not working for default param

Tags: python-unittest, freezegun

I am having a function with the a default value of a param as `datetime.now()`. method is something like below,

```
def as_standard_format(p_date=datetime.now(), fmt=sdk_constants.DEFAULT_DATE_TIME_FORMAT):
    return p_date.strftime(fmt)
```

And I am having a test method something like below,

```
@freeze_time(datetime(year=2018, month=9, day=25, hour=15, minute=46, second=36))
def testNowWithDefaultFormat(self):

    # The below method gives the frozen time
    print(datetime.now())

    # But the below test fails
    assert utils.format_date(
        datetime.now()) == "20180925T154636Z", "Default call not giving current time in " \
                                               "standard format \"%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ\""
```

Why is the `freeze_time` not working with default param value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're being victim of a [*common gotcha*](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) in Python related to mutable default value parameters and not specific only to `freeze_time`.

For the explanation, consider the following code:

```
import time from datetime import datetime

def what_time_is_it(p_date=datetime.now()):
    return p_date.strftime('"%Y-%m-%d %X"')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(what_time_is_it())
    time.sleep(10)
    print(what_time_is_it())
```

### What you might have expected to happen

```
"2019-02-28 13:47:24"
"2019-02-28 13:47:34" # This line showing a datetime 10 seconds after the first one
```

A new `datetime.now()` is called on every call to `what_time_is_it()`

### What does happen

```
"2019-02-28 13:47:24"
"2019-02-28 13:47:24" # EXACTLY the same time in both lines!
```

A new `datetime.now()` is created once when the function is defined, and the same value is used in each successive call.

### What you should do instead?

Create a new object each time the function is called, by using a default arg to signal that no argument was provided (**None** is often a good choice):

```
def as_standard_format(p_date=None, fmt=sdk_constants.DEFAULT_DATE_TIME_FORMAT):
    if p_date is None:
        return datetime.now().strftime(fmt)
    else:
        return p_date.strftime(fmt)
```