# mock function arguments in python

Tags: python, django, mocking, unit-testing

Lets say I have this function

```
from datetime import date

def get_next_friday(base_date=date.today()):
   next_friday = ...
   return next_friday
```

Then I have a celery task to call this function without passing in the `base_date`

```
@celery_app.task
def refresh_settlement_date():
   Record.objects.update(process_date=get_next_friday())
```

In the unittest I am running the `refresh_settlement_date()` task, but it's not providing the `base_date` when it's calling the `get_next_friday()`, my question is how to mock that parameter to test the days in the future?

I am trying to avoid adding parameter to become `refresh_settlement_date(base_date)` as it doesn't serve real purpose but only for unittest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [@patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) `get_next_friday()` function and substitute its return value with the one you need:

```
date_in_the_future = date.today() + timedelta(50)
next_friday_in_the_future = get_next_friday(base_date=date_in_the_future)

with patch('module_under_test.get_next_friday') as mocked_function:
    mocked_function.return_value = next_friday_in_the_future
    
    # call refresh_settlement_date
```

Comment: Thanks it's very similar to my own solution

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach would to be to patch the current date.

There is a relevant thread with multiple options:

- [Python: Trying to mock datetime.date.today() but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/python-trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working)

---

My favorite option is to use a third-party module called [`freezegun`](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/).

You would need only one line to add, very clean and readable:

```
@freeze_time("2014-10-14")
def test_refresh_settlement_date_in_the_future(self):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this out, it seems to work:

first I need to copy the function:

```
old_get_next_friday = get_next_friday
```

then patch it:

```
with patch.object(get_next_friday) as mocked_func:
    for i in range(8):
        mocked_func.return_value = old_get_next_friday(date.today() + timedelta(days=i))
        refresh_settlement_date()
```