# Is there a way I can use mock() (or similar) to mock the date & time for a script I *invoke* from a unit test?

Tags: python, datetime, mocking, unit-testing

I have written some unit tests using [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) in Python. However, they do not simply test objects in the conventional way - rather, they invoke another Python script by calling it using [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). This is by design - it's a command line utility, so I want to test it as a user would, which includes things such as command-line options, etc.). To be clear, both the unit tests and the script to be tested are written in Python (v3 to be precise).

The script I am testing makes heavy use of [datetime.now()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), and ideally I would like to mock that value somehow so that I can keep it constant. All the examples I've seen of doing this, though (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5437199/27641) using mock) assume some form of white-box testing.

Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from testing your CLI without using `Popen`. You just need to architect your code to make it possible:

Instead of having this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # ... Add args
    ns = parser.parse_args()
```

Do this:

```
import argparse

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # ... Add args
    parser.parse_args(argv[1:])  # This is the default for argparse
    ns = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    main(sys.argv)
```

Then, you can test the `main` function in isolation (just call `main([...])` with a set of args you specify). Note that this should also work (with some adaptation) for other CLI frameworks.

---

Also, note that if you're indeed using `argparse`, you'll need to patch `ArgumentParser()` so that it doesn't call `sys.exit` when parsing fails.

An easy way to do is to declare a `ParsingError` exception, and patch `ArgumentParser.error(self, message)` with:

```
def error(self, message):
    raise ParsingError(message)
```

You can then use `assertRaises` in your tests.

Comment: Note that this isn't hypothetical at all, and that you can see it in action in this project: https://github.com/Scalr/installer-ng/tree/master/wrapper/scalr-manage/scalr_manage — disclaimer: I wrote that code.

Comment: That's a neat idea, I hadn't thought of that. It's a little more complex than that, since my script also does other stuff such as fiddle with sys.excepthook, which might affect the unittest script. But this gives me a good place to start. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier You might be able to wrap `main(sys.argv)` in an `except` catch all and not have to fiddle with the excepthook (though this means you won't cover this in test). Also exemplified here ;) https://github.com/Scalr/installer-ng/blob/master/wrapper/scalr-manage/scalr_manage/cli.py#L98-L102