# Python: Mocking datetime.date.today()

Tags: python, unit-testing, date, datetime, mocking

Trying to get mocking to work for datetime.date.today() I finally got it working, after reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25652721/2285496) and this [documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#partial-mocking). I did not get my original version to work though, and I was wondering if anyone could help me understand?

My original implementation was to call `dt.date.today()` after importing datetime like this `import datetime as dt`. This can be seen in `mymodule.today_string_dt_date`. The testing was done by mocking `mymodule.dt.date` (not possible to mock `mymodule.dt.date.today` directly as it is a builtin), and setting `mock.today.return_value = dt.date(2016,1,10)` after importing `datetime` in the same way as in `mymodule.py` (`import datetime as dt`)

I then implemented a version that was importing `date` directly (`from datetime import date`) and created tests that was setting the `mock.today.return_value` to both `dt.date(2016,1,10)` and `date(2016,1,10)` for both versions. All test versions but my original one are passing, as can be seen in the output from running `py.test -v`

It looks like using the same import scheme (`import datetime as dt`) for both module and test and using that to create the mock return value (as in the test `test_today_string_dt_date`) ruins the mock.

#### mymodule.py

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date


def today_string_dt_date():
    return dt.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


def today_string_date():
    return date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(today_string_dt_date())
```

#### test_mymodule.py

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
from unittest.mock import patch
import unittest

import mymodule


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('mymodule.dt.date')
    def test_today_string_dt_date(self, mock_date):
        mock_date.today.return_value = dt.date(2016, 1, 10)
        assert mymodule.today_string_dt_date() == '2016-01-10'

    @patch('mymodule.dt.date')
    def test_today_string_dt_date_alt(self, mock_date):
        mock_date.today.return_value = date(2016, 1, 10)
        assert mymodule.today_string_dt_date() == '2016-01-10'

    @patch('mymodule.date')
    def test_today_string_date(self, mock_date):
        mock_date.today.return_value = dt.date(2016, 1, 10)
        assert mymodule.today_string_date() == '2016-01-10'

    @patch('mymodule.date')
    def test_today_string_date_alt(self, mock_date):
        mock_date.today.return_value = date(2016, 1, 10)
        assert mymodule.today_string_date() == '2016-01-10'
```

#### py.test output

```
=========================== test session starts ===========================
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.1, pytest-2.8.5, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
collected 4 items 

test_mymodule.py::MyTest::test_today_string_date PASSED
test_mymodule.py::MyTest::test_today_string_date_alt PASSED
test_mymodule.py::MyTest::test_today_string_dt_date FAILED
test_mymodule.py::MyTest::test_today_string_dt_date_alt PASSED

================================ FAILURES =================================
____________________ MyTest.test_today_string_dt_date _____________________

self = <test_mymodule.MyTest testMethod=test_today_string_dt_date>
mock_date = <MagicMock name='date' id='4364815888'>

    @patch('mymodule.dt.date')
    def test_today_string_dt_date(self, mock_date):
        mock_date.today.return_value = dt.date(2016, 1, 10)    
>       assert mymodule.today_string_dt_date() == '2016-01-10'
E       AssertionError: assert <MagicMock name='date().strftime()'     id='4353329528'> == '2016-01-10'
E        +  where <MagicMock name='date().strftime()' id='4353329528'> = <function today_string_dt_date at 0x10429ed90>()
E        +    where <function today_string_dt_date at 0x10429ed90> = mymodule.today_string_dt_date

test_mymodule.py:14: AssertionError
=================== 1 failed, 3 passed in 0.05 seconds ====================
```

Comment: One thing I like to do to aid testing is to make time-dependent functions take an optional argument. For example: `def some_function(dt=None): dt = datetime.now() if dt is None else dt` - this lets you skip mocking altogether.

Comment: Yeah, I see that as a great alternative. Thanks! My original code is bit more involved than the trimmed down version shown here and the function was called within another function. Then I would have to add `dt=None` to the calling function also? Not so sure if I like that. What if there are several of these cases? Could be I'm designing badly to begin with though..

Comment: With a keyword argument you could leave the callers alone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just because by `@patch('mymodule.dt.date')` you are patching the original `date` reference in `datetime` module. In this context `dt.date(2016, 1, 10)` is a `MagicMock` where the name is `date()`.

From this you have `today_string_dt_date()` will return a `date().strftime()` `MagicMock`.

I admit that is a little bit twisted and it is for this kind of things that I try avoid complicated paths in patch: my rules are

1. Try to patch just the root reference.
2. If you cannot follow *1* (module with `from a import b`) just patch the module reference and never browse from it.

Comment: So by using `@patch('mymodule.dt.date')`, I patch `datetime.date` globally? That is really confusing.. Thank you for the advice though! At least I learned to be a bit careful with complicated paths in patch.

Comment: I recommend this great read for python mocking gotchas: http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/