# How can I unit test a method using a datetime?

Tags: python, unit-testing, datetime

I have the follow class and method:

```
class DateTimeHelper(object):

    @staticmethod
    def get_utc_millisecond_timestamp():
        (dt, micro) = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').split('.')
        return "%s.%03d" % (dt, int(micro) / 1000)  # UTC time with millisecond
```

How can I unit test it? I am completely stumped although this is simple. It's my first unit test.

Comment: Mock out `utcnow` to return a known date-time?

Comment: You can "mock" the datetime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/python-trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`unittest.mock` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) (Python 3.3 and newer, backported as [`mock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock)), to replace calls to any code external to your code-under-test.

Here, I'd mock out not only `utcnow()` but `strftime()` too, to just return a string object:

```
with mock.patch('datetime.datetime') as dt_mock:
    dt_mock.utcnow.return_value.strftime.return_value = '2016-08-04 12:22:44.123456'
    result = DateTimeHelper.get_utc_millisecond_timestamp()
```

If you feel that testing the `strftime()` argument is important, give  `dt_mock.utcnow.return_value` an explicit `datetime` object to return instead; you'd have to create that test object *before* you mock however, as you can't mock out just the `datetime.datetime.utcnow` class method:

```
testdt = datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 4, 12, 22, 44, 123456)
with mock.patch('datetime.datetime') as dt_mock:
    dt_mock.utcnow.return_value = testdt
    result = DateTimeHelper.get_utc_millisecond_timestamp()
```

or, in your unittests, use `from datetime import datetime` to keep a reference to the class that isn't mocked.

Demo:

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> import datetime
>>> class DateTimeHelper(object):
...     @staticmethod
...     def get_utc_millisecond_timestamp():
...         (dt, micro) = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').split('.')
...         return "%s.%03d" % (dt, int(micro) / 1000)  # UTC time with millisecond
...
>>> with mock.patch('datetime.datetime') as dt_mock:
...     dt_mock.utcnow.return_value.strftime.return_value = '2016-08-04 12:22:44.123456'
...     result = DateTimeHelper.get_utc_millisecond_timestamp()
...
>>> result
'2016-08-04 12:22:44.123'
>>> testdt = datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 4, 12, 22, 44, 123456)
>>> with mock.patch('datetime.datetime') as dt_mock:
...     dt_mock.utcnow.return_value = testdt
...     result = DateTimeHelper.get_utc_millisecond_timestamp()
...
>>> result
'2016-08-04 12:22:44.123'
```

Comment: The [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) 3rd party module can also be quite useful and a time saver in some cases... (has handy decorators and context managers)

Comment: `freezegun` produces elaborate mocks; I've so far not seen any use case where you couldn't achieve the same with `mock`. With `mock` being the defacto standard I'm not sure I'd ever choose `freezegun` instead.

Comment: I've not seen where I couldn't reproduce anything using `urllib` that I couldn't with `requests`... it's mostly convenience - that's all.

Comment: @NinjaPuppy: the difference is much, much bigger between `urllib` and `requests` though. And `mock` lets me test, in detail, how my mocks were called, something `freezegun` doesn't let me do.

Comment: I'm not saying that one or t'other is best. For when I've used it for mocking, it's easier to classify an entire suite using known parameters than using context managers etc... like I said - it's just convenience...

Comment: This has got to be wrong, because it does not work whatsoever, what are you asserting? How is this a test?

Comment: @DIzzyDiza: I gave you the options to mock the `datetime` calls; you can now control the input and test the output against expected strings.