# Making a wrapper for `mock.patch`

Tags: python, testing, mocking, python-mock

Some customized patches from `mock.patch` I want to use over and over without littering my test code with copy-pastes of the patch setup. e.g. [this very handy patch of `datetime.date`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25652721/1464495), which, adapted for datetime, would fill my code with

```
with patch('mymodule.datetime') as mock_datetime:
    mock_datetime.datetime.utcnow.return_value = datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 8, 9, 10)
    mock_date.datetime.side_effect = lambda *args, **kw: datetime.datetime(*args, **kw)
```

How can I wrap this functionality into a one-line call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a resource manager class that will do that for you. Since you might want to put it in a separate file from your test classes, it uses `inspect` to look up the calling module, so that it can pass the correctly qualified target module name to `mock.patch`.

```
import datetime
import inspect
# import mock according to your python version

class mock_datetime(object):

    def __init__(self, target, new_utcnow):
        self.new_utcnow = new_utcnow
        self.target = target

    def __enter__(self):
        calling_module = inspect.getmodule(inspect.stack()[1][0])
        target_from_here = calling_module.__name__ + '.' + self.target
        self.patcher = mock.patch(target_from_here)
        mock_dt = self.patcher.start()
        mock_dt.datetime.utcnow.return_value = self.new_utcnow.replace(tzinfo=None)
        mock_dt.datetime.side_effect = lambda *args, **kw: datetime.datetime(*args, **kw)
        return mock_dt

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.patcher.stop()
```

You can then invoke it with

```
with mock_datetime('mymodule.datetime', datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 23)):
    assert mymodule.datetime.datetime.utcnow() == datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 23)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @brandones is excellent!  But I found it easier to use if you leave out the inspection, like this:

```py
# testhelpers.py
import unittest.mock as mock
import datetime

class MockDatetime():
    def __init__(self, target, utcnow):
        self.utcnow = utcnow
        self.target = target

    def __enter__(self):
        self.patcher = mock.patch(self.target)
        mock_dt = self.patcher.start()
        mock_dt.datetime.utcnow.return_value = self.utcnow.replace(tzinfo=None)
        mock_dt.datetime.side_effect = lambda *args, **kw: datetime.datetime(*args, **kw)
        return mock_dt

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.patcher.stop()


# testhelpers_test.py
import datetime
from testhelpers import MockDatetime

def test__mock_datetime():
    with MockDatetime('testhelpers_test.datetime', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 9, 10, 23, 1234)):
        assert datetime.datetime.utcnow() == datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 9, 10, 23, 1234)
```