# Mock datetime.datetime.now() while unit testing

Tags: python, datetime

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected_output", data)
def test_send_email(test_input, expected_output):
    emails = SendEmails(email_client=MagicMock())
    emails.send_email = MagicMock()
    emails.send_new_email(*test_input)
    emails.send_email.assert_called_with(*expected_output)
```

I am looking to mock datetime.datetime.now() which is called in the send_new_email method. I am unsure how to do it however.

I tried creating a new datetime object

```
 datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2017  1:33PM', 
                                          '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

and then overriding datetime.datetime.now

```
datetime.datetime.now = MagicMock(return_value=datetime_object)
```

However, I get the error

> TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'datetime.datetime'

*This question was marked as duplicate of Python: Trying to mock datetime.date.today() but not working*

[Python: Trying to mock datetime.date.today() but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/python-trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working)

I had already tried this solution but I could not get it to work. I cannot install freezegun due to the project requirements.

I have created a new class in the test file

```
class NewDate(datetime.date):
@classmethod
def today(cls):
    return cls(2010, 1, 1)
datetime.date = NewDate
```

But I have no idea how to get the SendEmails class to use this.

Comment: This seems to be a repost of your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410854/mock-datetime-datetime-now) which was already marked as a duplicate, any reason not to edit your previous question and try to get that reopened rather than repost?

Comment: I have commented on that question and edited it. But nothing happened. The help comment says to ask a new question so I did. Just following what stackoverflow says to do.

Comment: The problem here is that this is a carbon copy, you need to vote to have your previous question reopened, not to post an exact duplicate

Comment: The other question can be closed. I'm just following what the instructions say. I edited the question first and commented nothing happened. So I create this new question when I was able it. It has been upvoted so someone else must find this useful question.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the whole class:

```
_FAKE_TIME = 0
class _FakeDateTime(datetime.datetime):
    @staticmethod
    def now():
        return _FAKE_TIME
```

then to use it:

```
_FAKE_TIME = whatever
datetime.datetime = _FakeDateTime
```

The class needs some refinements like comparison operators to make a FakeDateTime comparable to a datetime, but it should work.

Comment: This can be improved by using a real `datetime` object instead of an `int`, similar to the question (no need to use `strptime`). For instance `_FAKE_TIME = datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1, 13, 33, 0)`. Now the return value from `_FakeDateTime.now` is a real fully functional `datetime` object. Patching is achieved with `monkeypatch.setattr(mymodule.datetime, "datetime", _FakeDateTime)`. This works because this is patching the reference to `datetime` in `mymodule` (your own module where this is running) instead of the `datetime` object itself.