# Date needs to be dynamically set so that test does not fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I'm writing a test for a specific function that I wrote the uses `datetime.utcnow()`, which is necessary as it functions in real-time. The test is shaped like this:

1.Test:

`*Important_Date, in datetime format*`

`Function which uses Important_Date`

`*assertfunction*`

2.Function which uses `Important_Date`

`if Condition:
        return Important_Date < (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7))`

Now, the problem is, whenever `Important_Date` is less than `7` days from `datetime.utcnow()`, the test case passes. If not, it fails.

Now, the requirement is that `Important_Date` should be set to something like one/two/three days before the date which I get from `datetime.utcnow()`. I'm confused as to how this is to be done.

I've tried `datetime.utcnow() - 1`, which is not working.

Is there a way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

I'm using Python 3, on PyCharm, running on Windows 10.

Comment: You can [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482067/4597780) `datetime.utcnow()` or use some tools like [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun).

Comment: freezegun worked. Thanks very much.