# Getting error while mocking datetime.datetime.now()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am new to Python. I am trying to mock datetime.datetime.now() but it is not working:

```
class Myclass:

   def update(self):

     time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s")
     ...
```

The above function is located in `mypackage/my_class.py`

While writing the test as follows taking idea from this post ([Trying to mock datetime.date.today(), but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working)):

```
@patch('mypackage.my_class.Myclass.datetime')
def test_update(self, datetime_mock):
  datetime_mock.datetime.now.return_value=datetime.datetime(2020,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

I am getting error as follows:

```
E           AttributeError: <class 'mypackage.my_class.Myclass'> does not have the attribute 'datetime'
```

Then I changed patching as below:

```
@patch('datetime')
def test_update(self, datetime_mock):
  datetime_mock.datetime.now.return_value=datetime.datetime(2020,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Now I am getting error as below:

```
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py:1591: in _get_target
    target, attribute = target.rsplit('.', 1)
E   ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

E   TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'datetime'
```

Comment: Could you add the import statement for datetime in your test and production code ? Could you also give the path of the file containing the MyClass class ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `freeze_time` from the `freezegun` module. I've modified `update()` to create a datetime string for readability in this test

```
class MyClass:
    def update(self):
        self.time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

```
from freezegun import freeze_time


class TestMyClass:
    @freeze_time("2020-03-01 12:31")
    def test_update(self):
        my_class = MyClass()
        my_class.update()
        assert my_class.time == "2020-03-01 12:31"
```

Hope this helps!