# Pytest: collection error, function uses no argument 'date'

Tags: python, pytest

Why does Pytest return the collection error "In test_billing_month_year: function uses no argument 'date" even though date is used and defined?

The function billing_month_year() simply returns the previous month and year of the current date.

```
import datetime as dt
import pytest 
from mock import patch

def billing_month_year():
    today = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    #last month from current date
    last_month = today.month - 1 if today.month>1 else 12
    #last year from current date
    last_month_year = today.year if today.month > last_month else today.year - 1
    return last_month, last_month_year

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'date, expected',
    [
        #last month in previous year
        (dt.datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=21), (12, 2019)),
        #last month in current year
        (dt.datetime(year=2020, month=2, day=21), (01, 2020)),
    ]
)
@patch('dt.datetime.utcnow')
def test_billing_month_year(date, expected, mock_utcnow):
    mock_utcnow.return_value = date
    test = billing_month_year()
    assert test == expected
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorators are always applied in the reverse order they are added, e.g. in this case first the `patch` decorator and then the `pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator is applied.
This means that the arguments shall be in the respective order:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'date, expected',
    [
        (dt.datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=21), (12, 2019)),
        (dt.datetime(year=2020, month=2, day=21), (01, 2020)),
    ]
)
@patch('dt.datetime.utcnow')
def test_billing_month_year(mock_utcnow, date, expected):
    mock_utcnow.return_value = date
    test = billing_month_year()
    assert test == expected
```

The patching probably won't work either, see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working) for solutions to this.

Comment: This worked thanks. As pointed out, patching datetimes does not work since python built in type are immutable. I was able to get around by using the [freezetime](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) and [forbiddenfruit](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit) libraries.