# Mock not seen by pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I got a class that describes an entity and am trying to write unit tests that should check if certain fields are defaulted to the correct value. One of those fields uses `datetime.now()` to set the default state.

I am having trouble trying to mock this call to `now()` in my test. I am guessing it has to do with my folder structure.

```
src
    classes
        MyClass.py
pytests
    test_MyClass.py
```

The MyClass definition:

```
from datetime import datetime
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mom = datetime.now()
```

I am using @mock.patch as follows (inside test_MyClass.py):

```
import pytest
import sys

from unittest import mock    
sys.path.append(r'C:\python-projects\test\src')
from classes.MyClass import MyClass
@mock.patch('classes.MyClass.datetime.now', return_value = 'timestamp', autospec = True)
@pytest.fixture
def myclass():
    myclass = MyClass()
    yield myclass
    
def test_has_datetime(myclass):
    assert myclass.mom == 'timestamp'
```

The test ignores the patch.

Comment: Is `datetime` actually a class attribute of `classes.MyClass`? Please give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's from the datetime library that comes with Python.

Comment: show the `MyClass.py` definition, can't help if we can't see the code

Comment: Oh, I see, `MyClass` is the module not the class. Presumably `MyClass` is imported from `classes.MyClass`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added the implementation of MyClass.

Comment: Please give an actual MRE. What's `sentiment`? What's imported to the tests? Does the mock work *outside* a fixture? What's the current output from running the test?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you should have that now. I tried removing some noise from the actual code and missed the sentiment.

Comment: @RuudVerhoef This post looks like it would be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working

Comment: @jdowner I edited the post with working code.... Feels like I am half awake... Ran this one before submitting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- make sure you have __init__.py files in `src`, `classes`and `pytests` directories;
- remove `sys.path.append(r'C:\python-projects\test\src')`
- in @mock.patch, replace `classes.MyClass.datetime.now` with `src.classes.MyClass.datetime.now`
- make `C:\python-projects\test\` the current working directory and run `pytest ./pytests`

Otherwise, mocking the datetime module can be easier with packages like `freezegun`: https://github.com/spulec/freezegun