# How to fix - TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'set'

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and I'm trying to make a simple GUI chat with python. It is programmed to ask for a nickname when a client joins the server. All works fine until the part where I enter the nickname. When I enter the nickname I get these errors from the server and client respectively, I'll provide the tracebacks as well.

`ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`
(From server)

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 51, in <module>
    receive()
  File "server.py", line 44, in receive
    broadcast(f"{nickname} entered to the chat!\n".encode('utf-8'))
  File "server.py", line 17, in broadcast
    client.send(message)
```

`TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'set'`
(from client)

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ISINDU WICKRAMASEKAR/PycharmProjects/guichat/client.py", line 94, in <module>
    client = Client(HOST, PORT)
  File "C:/Users/ISINDU WICKRAMASEKAR/PycharmProjects/guichat/client.py", line 22, in __init__
    set.gui_done = False
```

The code for the server and client are also linked.

server -> https://pastebin.com/0W7Cw9Cu

client-> https://pastebin.com/FES2UNc1

What I have tried:

I tried googling for answers and I can't say I didn't get any, but I didn't understand how to implement those solutions for my issue. These are the links I referred to

1. [Python handling socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568216/python-handling-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer)
2. [python can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319999/python-cant-set-attributes-of-built-in-extension-type-object)

Comment: Including your code directly in the question is preferred over linking it. How much to include is a judgment call. Large code-blocks will be given their own scroll-bar so they don't clutter the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message points us to the problem pretty precisely.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ISINDU WICKRAMASEKAR/PycharmProjects/guichat/client.py", line 94, in <module>
    client = Client(HOST, PORT)
  File "C:/Users/ISINDU WICKRAMASEKAR/PycharmProjects/guichat/client.py", line 22, in __init__
    set.gui_done = False
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'set' (from client)
```

On line 22 of client.py, you try to assign `set.gui_done = False`; you probably meant `self.gui_done`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line

```
set.gui_done = False
```

`set` is a protected keyword in python. It's reserved for the `set` data type. With this line youre telling the interpreter to change the `gui_done` attribute of the in-built `set` type to false which is not allowed. That's why you're getting a `TypeError`. If it wasn't an in-built type you'd still get an `AttributeError` because `set` doesn't have a `gui_done` attribute. You probably meant to use `self` instead of `set`