# Which objects in Python can have attributes added dynamically?

Tags: python, oop, object, dynamic, attributes

In Python, I can add an attribute to a class `C` which I have previously defined. However, I cannot add an attribute to `list` - the resulting error message explains that this is because `list` is a built-in type:

```
>>> class C: pass
...
>>> C.foo = 1
>>> C.foo
1

>>> list.foo = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'list'
```

Similarly, it is possible to add an attribute to an instance of `C`, but not to an instance of `list`. In this case, however, the error message is much more vague:

```
>>> o = C()
>>> o.bar = 2
>>> o.bar
2

>>> o = []
>>> o.bar = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Why can't I add members to instances of `list`? Is it, again, because `list` is a built-in type?

More generally, which objects in Python can have attributes added dynamically?

Comment: I guess to anything that is not an inbuilt type

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738987/extension-method-for-python-built-in-types

Comment: Generally not builtin types. The only slight surprise is that you can add attributes to ordinary functions. Google for PEP 232.

Answer (score 2):

When setting arbitrary properties on an object, this effectively mutates the object’s `__dict__`. The `__dict__` is a dictionary that stores all members of the object. So in order to add members to an object, there are two conditions:

1. The object needs to have a `__dict__`.
2. The object’s `__dict__` needs to be mutable.

There are multiple reasons why one of these conditions may not be true. The following categories of types will *usually* do not allow object modifications:

- Built-in *native* types are implemented in native code and have a fixed set of members, baked into their native object definition. Examples include `int`, `str`, `list`, `bytes`, … probably most (but not all) [built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)
- *Native* types from external libraries, for example numpy stuff.
- Any Python class that is using [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). Slots is an explicit way to turn of the `__dict__` and replace it by a fixed set of members instead. So obviously, this will prevent later additions to the object (per design).

What are good ways to detect whether you can modify an object? Well, check conditions from above. Whether the object has a `__dict__`:

```
>>> class Example:
        pass
>>> class SlotsExample:
        __slots__ = ['x']

>>> hasattr(Example(), '__dict__')
True
>>> hasattr(SlotsExample(), '__dict__')
False
>>> hasattr(list, '__dict__')
True
>>> hasattr([], '__dict__')
False
```

And whether the `__dict__` is a real dictionary:

```
>>> isinstance(Example().__dict__, dict)
True
>>> isinstance(list.__dict__, dict)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, it depends on `__setattr__` magic method.

Python attributes are retrieved via `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`. In case you have a class without them, the defaults apply. (Slots are a little different.)

For built-in/extension types (`HEAPTYPE` in CPython), you can't add any other attributes by default, but you can, however, override it by providing another function. (Impossible with pure Python.)