# How can I make all Python3 numbers ctypes.c_int32?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, numbers, ctypes

I am trying to replicate C program behaviours using Python3 and repeatedly casting all numbers to ctypes.c_int32 get ugly real fast.

Is there any way I could default Python's int to be an instance of ctypes.c_int32?

Edit:
I would like to perform arithmetic operations between multiple c_int32 objects (e.g. xor-ing and and-ing), but I can't do this without adding `.value` behind every c_type int object. I want to see if I can somehow override the default python `int` object to behave more similarly to `c_int32` in ctypes.

Comment: It isn't really even clear what you mean, but no, no there isn't. Operations involving `ctypes` objects should return the same kind of object, so it what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: If your real purpose is only to simplify the way you do arithmetic with `c_int32` objects, you could create your own class inheriting from `ctypes.c_int32` that overloads its `__xor__` and `__and__` operators.

Comment: @vultkayn How can I make what you said the default behavior of Python numbers?

Comment: You can't, at most you can add method to builtin types (such as int), but it is impossible to overload an existing method. I have myself tried to, but without any success. See this post for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738987/extension-method-for-python-built-in-types
Since you are already using explicit `c_int32` objects instead of `int`, it shouldn't be much of an issue to replace it by your own, let's say, `my_cint32` type

Comment: There are too few details, but looks like an *XY Problem*. Why would one need that? It's easier to write in *C* than in *CTypes* (and it will also be faster). Also what do you want to do with the numbers? what if you'd subclass *CTypes* types that you use and add appropriate magic methods (*\_\_add\_\_*, ...)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Show example code of whatever you’re trying to do. Don’t make us guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want in Python 3.  `int` in Python 2.3 and earlier (before int/long integration) worked they way I think you want.

If you just want to constrain math results to signed int32 results `ctypes` isn't needed.  The following truncates `n` to the lower 32 bits, then adjusts for the sign bit:

```py
>>> def int32(n):
...   n &= (1<<32)-1
...   return n - (1<<32) if n & (1<<31) else n
...
>>> int32(-1)
-1
>>> int32(0x80000000)  # sign bit set (bit 31)
-2147483648
>>> int32(0x7fffffff)  # max positive int32
2147483647
>>> int32(0x7fffffff + 1)  # overflow to sign bit
-2147483648
>>> 1<<31         # without constraint
2147483648
>>> int32(1<<31)
-2147483648
>>> 1<<32         # without constraint
4294967296
>>> int32(1<<32)
0
```