# Adding method to lambda in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I want to do something like this in python:

```
(lambda: ... some code ...).valueHandling(...some parameters)
```

That is, I want to extend the type `function` with a new method called `valueHandling`.
I tried different thing like:

1)

```
def valueHandling(self):
  ...

function.valueHandling=valueHandling
```

2)

```
function.__class__.__dict__['valueHandling']=valueHandling
```

3) etc

None worked...
Is there a way to do it? To add a method to function so all 'lambdas' can respond to that method?

Thanks

Comment: I'm really confused as to what you want to happen here. What does *respond to* mean in your final sentence?

Comment: @Lattyware he wants to add a new method to all function objects

Comment: what? that doesnt make sense still ...

Comment: You can't extend function in a way that affects the core `function` type. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192649/can-you-monkey-patch-methods-on-core-types-in-python

Comment: @JoranBeasley He wants to alter all `lambda`s so that they all have a `.valueHandling()` method/function

Comment: could you write it as: `valueHandling(lambda x,y,z: ... some code ..., ...some other parameters)`

Comment: `self` parameter is only for unbound methods (methods defined on the class). You are setting an attribute directly on the object. It should not have a `self` parameter

Answer (score 0):

CPython doesn't allow this:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'function'
```

(and if you try to use the `.__dict__` method...)

```
TypeError: 'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment
```

This is because these types are implemented in C and trade flexibility for speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set properties of individual (function/lambda/etc..) objects:

```
l = lambda x: x*2
def fun():
  return 1
l.f = fun
l.f()
1
```

You cannot do this for *all* functions - you have to manually add it to each of them.

You could write a short wrapper, and then `mylambda(lambda x: ...)` :

```
def mylambda(x):
  x.f = fun
  return x
```

Comment: Thank you all! It is a pity Python does not allow you to add functionality to core classes like function... I wanted to do that to implement exception just using objects and without the try/except sintax. I just did it as Karoly suggested. Thanks!

Comment: From the documentation:
""Function objects also support getting and setting arbitrary attributes, which can be used, for example, to attach metadata to functions. Regular attribute dot-notation is used to get and set such attributes. Note that the current implementation only supports function attributes on user-defined functions. Function attributes on built-in functions may be supported in the future""