# Python 3 / Django 1.8 check domain ownership

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to check domain ownership by reading domain's TXT records. But it seem all library handle that job were written in python 2.x
I have used: 
dns.resolver
domcheck
but all of them fail with error: `'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`
Can I do that in Python 3.x ?

Comment: You could fork the library and modify it for Python 3.x (e.g. by switching to `.items` instead of `.iteritems`).

Comment: Unfortunately what @jonrsharpe seems to be the only option, because you cannot monkey-patch built-in data-types. You would have to fix the `dict` implementation, which is not possible. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192649/can-you-monkey-patch-methods-on-core-types-in-python/192857#192857 

Perhaps this is the time to fork the project, create a Python 3.x version and contribute your changes to the original project. :)