# Add percentage symbol to all list elements

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Hi I have a list like this: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

I want to add `"%"` to all these elements in the list for a result of `[1%,2%,3%,4%,5%,6%]`.

I know that I can do it with `+"%"` but how can i do it with `.format` or another thing?

Comment: This link might help you https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html

Answer (score 2):

This [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/) help

```
['{:d}%'.format(elm) for elm in l]
```

Output :

```
['1%', '2%', '3%', '4%', '5%', '6%']
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do it with `format`, your results of course need to be strings:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
r = list(map("{}%".format, l))
```

now, `r` is:

```
['1%', '2%', '3%', '4%', '5%', '6%']
```

Alternatively you could do it with a list-comp as in the other answer or, in place, by looping:

```
for ind, i in enumerate(l):
    l[ind] = "{}%".format(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've asked: `or another thing?` I'll give you `another thing`.

Sometimes, you'd desire something, which seems little bad, like this:

```
# add method to built-in int class to render ints as percents
as_percent = lambda x: str(x) + '%'
# and then monkey patch it
int.as_percent = as_percent
```

However you'd end up with this `Exception`:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'
```

But, there is a way..

Before you'd will try the following a *little disclaimer*:

> I've never used this in any actual code, but I find this very fun, and generaly good to know it exists. Having code a little bit in Ruby, I like the idea of monkey patching built-ins. But it is not default behaviour in Python. So, be aware. But at least, try it!

First you need this module `forbiddenfruit` (see, the **name** is quite self-explanatory!). Simply `pip` it.

Then it is quite easy. We'll use the exact same `lambda` function `as_percent` as before.

```
>>> from forbiddenfruit import curse
>>> # again, do you see the name of the function?!
>>> curse(int, 'as_percent', as_percent)
>>> print((1).as_percent())
1%
>>> [x.as_percent() for x in range(10)]
>>> ['0%', '1%', '2%', '3%', '4%', '5%', '6%', '7%', '8%', '9%']
```

I've come across it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246179/2377489).