# "Replacing" specific function calls

Tags: python, python-2.7, monkeypatching, sage

This is a question about Sage, which is based on Python 2.7.  I've written up the sage question [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/39807/replacing-function-calls-in-special-cases/), but will modify that question to remove the mathematical context.

I'm trying to improve the speed of a few slow functions for very specific cases.
Essentially, I have a function `foo`, such that `foo(args)` is traditionally quite slow, but but due to analysis I've done by hand, `foo(args')` can be easily computed via `bar(args')` (for special cases of `args'` that are easy to check in practice).  I'd like to have a new version of `foo` such that:

1. If `args == args'`, (or `args in A`, where `A` is some data structure that contains all inputs `bar` is correct for) it just calls `bar(args)`
2. Otherwise, it calls `foo(args)`

Now, if `foo` were just defined in my own code, this would be trivial to fix (by modifying the definition, or potentially a decorator).

My issue is that `foo` is in `module1` (not my code).  `module2` imports `foo` as well, and I want this change to be visible to everything in `module2` as well (essentially, I myself never call `foo`, so for the speedup to occur I need other functions to compute the specific case quicker).

I have my own code that imports `module1` and `module2`.  Is there a way I could modify `foo` (from within my own code) to handle this special case faster, so that when functions in `module1` and `module2` call it they'll get the speedup as well?  This is only really useful if it's possible without modifying the source code of `module1` and `module2`.

**EDIT**

In light of the answer below, are there ways to monkey-patch calls to PARI in Sage?  The method I'm trying to monkey-patch is described by the profiler as `{method '_nf_rnfeq' of 'sage.libs.cypari2.gen.gen' objects}`.
In light of this, I tried the following, which didn't work.

```
import sage.libs.cypari2.gen
orig_nf_rnfeq = sage.libs.cypari2.gen.gen._nf_rnfeq
def _nf_rnfeq(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Rnfeq works!")
    return orig_nf_rnfeq(*args, **kwargs)

sage.libs.cypari2.gen.gen._nf_rnfeq = _nf_rnfeq
```

This leads to the error `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'sage.libs.cypari2.gen.gen`

Answer (score 1):

```
import module1
origfoo = module1.foo

def myfoo(*args):
    if args in A:
        return bar(*args)
    return origfoo(*args)

module1.foo = myfoo
```

Any module that imports `module1` after this point will pick up your modified version of the function.  You might have a problem if `module1` itself imports `module2` before you have a chance to apply the patch.

Comment: Upon trying to implement this, I get the following error: `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'sage.libs.cypari2.gen.gen'`.  It seems related to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192649/can-you-monkey-patch-methods-on-core-types-in-python), so I'll try looking into that.