One-line command to raise an Exception with a note?
I want this output:
RuntimeError: Unable to parse Powershell-encoded commands.
was a `{$...}` left in the command?

Process finished with exit code 1

I would like to use code like this:
if sys.argv[1] == '-encodedCommand':
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to parse Powershell-encoded commands.").with_note('was a `{$...}` left in the command?')

This code does what I want, but it looks ugly:
if sys.argv[1] == '-encodedCommand':
    to_raise =  RuntimeError(f"Unable to parse Powershell-encoded commands.")
    to_raise.add_note('was a `{$...}` left in the command?')
    raise to_raise


The reason I want to add a note rather than a linebreak in the Exception message is that I see "Unable to parse Powershell-encoded commands." as the actual problem that belongs in the Exception message, and "was a `{$...}` left in the command?" is just my two cents to help with troubleshooting. 
I'm open to the idea that I'm mistaken on what's good practice for Exception messages.

If raise MyRuntimeError(...).with_note(...) would suffice, just write a class extending RuntimeError. Or a function, raise create_runtime_error(..., notes=[...]). But you can't monkeypatch core types: https://stackoverflow.com/q/192649/3001761.

Notes aren't designed to be used at the point where an exception was raised. They're for other code that wants to add information later. Are you just doing this because you want to put a line break in your exception message?

In general, Python doesn't use fluent interfaces. Methods that modify the object in place return None, they don't return the object that was modified. So one-liners like that are not considered pythonic and they're not easy to write.

And if the designers wanted to make it easy to add a note when you're creating the exception, it would have been a parameter to the constructor.

@Barmar There's a BaseException.with_traceback() method, but I see your point about the designers making it a parameter to the constructor.

the code looks fine. there is no need to do things on one line, and in this case, that isn't how the interface is designed

@DanielLawson There are exceptions. SQLAlchemy uses a fluent interface in its query builder.
